# Python Maya - If objectType returns "No object name specified"

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to get maya to check if the listed object is a blendshape node or not.

This is my code:

```
def bake(self, *args):
    self.items["selection"] = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    self.items["shapes"] = cmds.listRelatives(self.items["selection"], ad = True)
    shapes = ()
    for i in self.items["shapes"]:
        bs = cmds.listConnections(i, type = "blendShape", exactType = True)
        if cmds.objectType(bs, isType = "blendShape"):
            print bs
```

It returns `# Error: RuntimeError: file X:/Documents/maya/scripts\jtBakeCharacter.py line 16: No object name specified`

Line 16 is: `if cmds.objectType(bs, isType = "blendShape"):`

Except that I AM specifying an object name, that object name is bs .. I have printed the result of bs and it has many objects listed. Many.

Answer (score 3):

The code is redundant. You don't need most of the lines. The *listConnections* already ensures that you have only blendshapes. The exact problem is that you are calling something like:

```
cmds.objectType([])
```

for some of those extra shapes. And this is illegal. But mostly you code can be encapsulated as follows:

```
selected = cmds.ls(sl = True, dag=True ,shapes = True)
blends = cmds.listConnections(selected , type = "blendShape", exactType = True)
for item in blends:
    print item
```

But this may not catch your intent perfectly, but shows how may extra steps you take. In reality you don't need the line **if cmds.objectType(bs, isType = "blendShape"):** for anything

Answer (score 1):

Joojaa's answer is elegant, but you can get it down even shorter by using the default selection behavior:

```
blendshapes = cmds.ls(cmds.listHistory(pdo=True), type='blendShape') or []
for item in blendshapes:
    print item
```

(In the quest to make it even shorter I'm not checking for the selection, so this one fails if nothing is selected).

PS: if you need to get to the blendshape from one of the upstream shapes, instead of the deformed shape, you can use listHistory (f=True)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
from pymel.core import *

for obj in selected():
    shapeNode = obj.getChildren()[0]
    for output in shapeNode.outputs():
        if nodeType(output) == "blendShape":
            print obj, "is a blendshape"
```